# Renaming or Moving html files in Visual Studio 2012 breaks links and dependencies

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, expression-web

Microsoft Expression Web 4 enables you to maintain the dependencies between the webpages in your website by means of this feature;

**Site > Site Setting > Maintain the site using hidden metadata files**

As a result of this feature, you can MOVE and RENAME the webpages in a simple website without breaking the dependency between these pages.

If you rename a css file, all html pages that makes reference to that css file upadate thier code to reflect the new name automatically. The same is for moving files.

=========

My Problem

I HAVE TO use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to create websites not ASP.NET website. Just plain simple html5 website.

I have however realised that MOVING or RENAMING html or css files BREAKS the dependencies between these files.

=======

My Question

Is there any way that Microsoft Visual Studio can be made to behave like Expression Web such that moving or renaming files will automatically update references everywhere in the website.

Note: I do not have this problem with WPF applications, only websites.